# Calling a stored PROCEDURE in Toad

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I have a defined a new stored procedure but get a error while calling it,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCOTT.getempsal(
        p_emp_id IN NUMBER,
        p_emp_month IN CHAR,
        p_emp_sal OUT INTEGER)

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EMP_SAL
      INTO p_emp_sal
      FROM EMPLOYEE_SAL
    WHERE  EMP_ID = p_emp_id
    AND    EMP_MONTH = p_emp_month;

END getempsal;
```

And trying to call it:

```
getempsal(1,'JAN',OUT) --Invalid sql statement.
```

Comment: Toad is a **GUI based client tool**, unlike SQL*Plus. So, you could directly view the Procedure and execute it from the tool itself.

Answer (score 16):

Your procedure contains an out parameter, so you need to call it in block like:

```
declare
a number;
begin 
  getempsal(1,'JAN',a);
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
end;
```

A simple procedure (let's say with a number parameter) can be called with

```
exec proc(1);
```

or

```
begin
proc(1);
end;
```

Comment: If procedure returns cursor, just declare it and then do the following:
:output := cursor;
This will print the cursor content in the data grid.

Comment: One more useful thing - you can all stored procedure with output cursor like this:
exec package_name.procedure_name('param', 'param2', :0)
and you'll get cursor content in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Just write EXECUTE procedure_name('provide_the_valueof_IN parameter','value of in parameter', :k) ;

Run this statement a popup will come set the parameters as in out and the datatype too. U will see the output in another popup window.